# how to create a polymorphe couple such as "( a : type A, b : type B ) " in lambda-calculus

Tags: coq, lambda-calculus, coqide

I am working on a project in Lambda-calculus and i am trying to code polymorphe couple with coqide
but a have a problem coding the constructor that respect the type pprod

```
Definition pprod : Set -> Set -> Set  := fun A B => forall T : Set , (A -> B -> T) -> T.
```

I have a problem with pcpl

```
Definition pcpl : Set -> Set -> pprod :=
  fun A B T  : Set => fun (a : A) (b : B) => fun k : A -> B -> T => k a b.
```

this is the error i get :

```
The term "pprod" has type "Set -> Set -> Set"
which should be Set, Prop or Type.
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem doesn't lie already in the definition of `pprod`? I'm unable to make your definition of `pprod` typecheck.

Comment: You have two options: replace `Set` with `Prop` everywhere, or replace `Set -> Set -> Set` with `Set -> Set -> Type`. The problem is that you are quantifying over `Set`, so either you need to use polymorphism in Coq and quantify over `Prop`, or the product needs to be in a bigger universe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are quantifying over `Set`, so the resulting product type cannot be of type `Set`, but of a larger type `Type`.  So your definition should look like

```
   Definition pprod : Set -> Set -> Type  := fun A B => forall T : Set , (A -> B -> T) -> T.
```

the constructor for products should look like

```
Definition pcpl (A : Set) (B : Set) : A -> B -> pprod A B :=
  fun (a : A) (b : B) => fun T  : Set =>  fun k : A -> B -> T => k a b.
```

An alternative way to approach this is to use the polymorphic types in Coq, namely the types in `Prop`:

```
 Definition pprod : Prop -> Prop -> Prop  := 
fun A B => forall T : Prop , (A -> B -> T) -> T.
Definition pcpl (A : Prop) (B : Prop) : A -> B -> pprod A B :=
  fun (a : A) (b : B) => fun T  : Prop =>  fun k : A -> B -> T => k a b.
```

Note the universes in Coq are a bit confusing. See [What is different between Set and Type in Coq?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/80729/what-is-different-between-set-and-type-in-coq) for details.

I'm going to take this opportunity to advertise the new [Proof Assistants](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.